# 「ありがとうございや」 - Dialect? Train Station 言葉？

Tags: dialects, greetings

Today as I was transferring trains in Nagoya the station attendant was shouting repeatedly「ありがとうございや」. Doing a search on the internet revealed that this seems to be a shorted form of ありがとうございやした but I have never heard of this before.

Is this from a specific dialect/age group/group
Is it's usage just a simple replacement of 「ま」in 「～ました」
Can this be done to any verb, or is it limited to 「る」ending verbs that conjugate to 「い」in 丁寧語 (polite speech)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be ありがとうございやす with devoiced す.  [ございやす](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%94%E3%81%96%E3%81%84%E3%82%84%E3%81%99&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0), whose meaning is the same as ございます, was used in the Edo dialect in the 16th–19th centuries, and seems to be still in use in the Ibaraki dialect.  I do not think that either ありがとうございや or ありがとうございやす is used in the Nagoya dialect.

Answer (score 4):

I have thought without much grounds that this is an Edo word (江戸言葉). You can see it in 時代劇 such as 水戸黄門. But this also seems to be a 役割語 'stereotyped role words' that is assumed to be used by a lower-rank gangster/thief against the leader of the group. I am not sure whether it is actually so. I am surprised to hear that it is heard in present Nagoya.

This form is applied to any verb.

> 金庫を開けやした、親分。[consonant verb]
>
> 'I opened the safe, my leader.'
>
> 茂吉の奴をここで見やした。 [vowel verb]
>
> 'I saw the guy Mokichi here.'
>
> 奴が来やした。 [irregular verb]
>
> 'The guy just arrived.'
>
> 物(ぶつ)を手配しやした。 [irregular verb]
>
> 'I made an arrangement for the thing.'